# How can I always allowing micrphone and camera access from local files in browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc

I'm currently working on a project that uses raspberry pis to communicate with WebRTC. I want one pi to initiate a call with the press of a single button for emergency purposes. Initiating the call means, waking up, opening a browser full screen and starting the call. The problem is that Chromium has a pop up that asks if you want to allow the microphone and camera to be accessed by the browser. I would like to always allow this but the address is a local file and not a site I can add to Chromium's trusted list. Is there a way to circumvent this? Is there another browser I can trust to run quickly on a raspberry pi?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you tried starting chrome with --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream? Caveat: will allow camera without prompt for *everything*

Answer (score 0):

"have you tried starting chrome with --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream? Caveat: will allow camera without prompt for everything – Philipp Hancke 19 hours ago" -first comment

Thanks!